# Repartir um número de 16 dígitos no PHP

Tags: php

Número: **9999999999999999**
Ficar assim: **9999 9999 9999 9999**

```
$num1 = "9999"; //parte 1
$num2 = "9999"; //parte 2
$num3 = "9999"; //parte 3
$num4 = "9999"; //parte 4
```

Gostaria de fazer isso, sem perder nenhum número ou somar nada, apenas deixando em 4 partes na ordem que estava.

Answer (score 12):

Pode quebrar essa string em partes iguais com a função [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php) que retorna um array. Ela é parecicda com `explode()` mas no lugar de quebrar a string por um delimitador `str_split()` faz o mesmo apenas, baseado em um tamanho fixo.

```
$arr = str_split('9999999999999999', 4);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9999
    [1] => 9999
    [2] => 9999
    [3] => 9999
)
```

Outra forma de separar e formatar essa string é com [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) que adiciona o(s) caracter(es) a cada intervalo, note que ao final da string também foi adicionado um underline pode remover ele com [`rtirm()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) e especificar o caracter que deseja remover.

```
echo chunk_split('9999999999999999', 4, '_');
echo rtrim(chunk_split('9999999999999999', 4, '_'), '_');
```

Saída:

```
9999_9999_9999_9999_
9999_9999_9999_9999
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: O intuito dessa função é quebra-los, correto?
str_split('9999999999999999', 4);

Mas e a função de pegar o número repartido?
Assim como disse.
$num1 = "9999"; //parte 1
$num2 = "9999"; //parte 2
$num3 = "9999"; //parte 3
$num4 = "9999"; //parte 4

Comment: @WolfProg. você quer juntar ou repartir o número? ou so adicionar espaços a cada 4 caracteres?

Comment: Veja a documentação do str_split(), é muito interativa...
mas essa função mesmo que vai te ajudar a resolver o seu problema... ele vai transformar seu número em "arrays"

Comment: Darley, abaixo, já resolveu meu problema. Mas mesmo assim ajudou muito na ética da resolução.

Comment: Você vai repartir os números e imprimir da forma que quiser no front-end... caso queira jogar dessa forma no banco de dados... terá que adicionar um espaço vazio entre os números...
Isso, na verdade, é uma boa fazer no javascript, é uma tarefa mais para front-end... se a sua duvida for essa mesmo... imprimir na tela!

Answer (score 8):

Baseado na resposta do @rray

```
$separado = implode(' ', str_split('9999999999999999', 4));
```

Se quisesse com pontos:

```
$separado = implode('.', str_split('9999999999999999', 4));
```

Como já explicado, o `split` divide a string em partes iguais. Complementarmente o `implode` "cola" os pedaços separados, usando uma *string* à sua escolha entre eles.

Se um espaço extra no final não for um problema, vide alternativa mais elegante com `chunk_split` na resposta mencionada.

Caso o número de dígitos varie e você queira algo como

```
99 9999 9999
```

pode usar esta alternativa:

```
for($i=strlen($string); $i>0; $i-=4) $string=substr_replace($string, ' ', $i, 0);
```

Ela insere os espaços "do fim pro começo". Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/p1fg5K)**.

Answer (score 7):

Serão sempre 16 digitos?? Pode resolver de uma forma bem simples

```
$str = "9999999999999999";
$num1 = substr($str, 0, 4);
$num2 = substr($str, 4, 4);
$num3 = substr($str, 8, 4);
$num4 = substr($str, 12, 4);
```

> [Leia mais na Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 3):

Se você levar em consideração a pontuação em casa decimal monetária, você terá que inverter o valor da string para poder pontuar corretamente e depois reverter para ter o valor da string original pontuada.

```
var_dump(formater("1234567891234567",5,"."));

function formater($str_number, $quantity, $char){
    $arr_number_reverse = array_reverse(str_split($str_number));
    $separado = implode($char, str_split(implode($arr_number_reverse), $quantity));
    return implode(array_reverse(str_split($separado)));
}
```

**Faça o teste, mude a quantidade de casa a ser aplicado o caractere escolhido...

Baseado na solução do *Bacco*.