# Como dividir uma string a cada 2 caracteres?

Tags: java, string

Estou tentando dividir uma string a cada dois caracteres, mas não tenho um delimitador e preciso utilizar toda a string.

Exemplo:

```
String exemplo= 99E65A78

String ex1= 99
String ex2= E6
String ex3= 5A
String ex4= 78
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Repartir um número de 16 dígitos no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250185/repartir-um-n%c3%bamero-de-16-d%c3%adgitos-no-php)

Comment: Ela pode usar a lógica da questão para conseguir fazer, mas ela não citou a linguagem.

Comment: Assim como citado pelo @DarleiFernandoZillmer é necessário informar a linguagem que você esta utilizando para podermos ajudá-la

Comment: Oi, desculpe. É em java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    "8S8Q4D1SKCQC2C4S6H4C6DJS2S1C6C".split("(?<=\\G.{2})")
));
```

Comment: Resolveu. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Você poderia explicar o que a regex está fazendo.

Comment: Você resolve o problema mas não explica a solução. Isso não contribui para solucionar a dúvidas de pessoas mais novas na area.

Answer (score 6):

Eu faria assim:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String texto = "99E65A78";
        List<String> partes = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i += 2) partes.add(texto.substring(i, Math.min(i + 2,texto.length())));
        for (int i = 0; i < partes.size(); i++) System.out.println(partes.get(i));
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pcgJPG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cwcolorp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/SplitFixed.java).

Vou pulando a cada 2 caracteres e guardando em uma lista. Só tomo o cuidado de não pegar um caractere menor que o tamanho.

O segundo laço é só para mostrar.

Tem outras formas de fazer, mas esta deve ser a mais performática e é muito simples.

Comment: Só trocaria o 2 por uma constante, caso ele queira variar por n caracteres, teria que alterar só em um canto. (:

Comment: @FelipeAvelar eu até pensei nisso e gosto muito da ideia, só achei exagero para demonstrar aqui. Ainda vou dar uma garibada nele e mexo nisto também (estou precisando otimizar tempo esses dias).

Comment: Valeu. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma seria usando um `while`:

```
String text = "99E65A78"
List<String> stringSerparada = new ArrayList<String>();
int index = 0;
while (index < text.length()) {
      stringSerparada.add(text.substring(index, Math.min(index+2,text.length()));
      index+= 2;
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que você [perdeu o _timing_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257355/64969)...

Comment: É verdade @JeffersonQuesado enquanto estava fazendo ele postou kkk

Comment: Eu pensei que havia sido a mesma resposta, agora que percebi que você usou `while`, portanto é ligeiramente distinto...

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver fazendo em java.
Você pode utilizar o "substring". Eu fiz manualmente, porém você pode criar um delimitador utilizando um laço de repetição e trabalhar em cima dele.

Ex:

```
    String texto = "99E65A78";
    String EX = "";

    EX = texto.substring(0, 2);
    System.out.println(EX);
    EX = texto.substring(2, 4);
    System.out.println(EX);
    EX = texto.substring(4, 6);
    System.out.println(EX);
    EX = texto.substring(6, 8);
    System.out.println(EX);
```

Comment: E se o tamanho da string não puder ser determinado?

Comment: @Articuno , por isso que o AR pôs como nota no texto "utilizando laço de repetição", perto da observação "fiz manualmente, porém"